# sphinx - which id to which index?

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm using sphinx to search our database.  In this example, I'm querying two indexes; index1 and index2.

```
$res = $cl->Query( $query, "index1 index2" );
```

The results are good, but I can't distinguish the resulting IDs from index1 and index2 from within the code.  Is there a way I can make all IDs coming from index1 look like: in1_1, in1_600, in1_x... So I can distinguish between them?

Comment: If you need to distinguish which index is providing which result, you will need to query each index separately.

Comment: I thought about doing that, but then I was confused about how to weigh the two result sets.

Comment: If I recall correctly, a weight attribute is passed back with the results. Could you use that to resort the two arrays?

Comment: I could, but the weights between index1 and index2 would then be independent of one another. So my resort would not be the most efficient result set.  I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setup a attribute that identifies which index it came from, see

http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=5653

Comment: Ah, genius!  Thanks for finding this!